# How to select a specific element after using random function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used random function for a list in my code and i am not able to select a specific element.

Code

```
import random
lst=['black','blue','green','red','yellow']
lst1=[1,2,3,4,5]
for a in range(1,4):
    l=random.choice(lst1)
    l1=random.choice(lst)
    print(l,l1)
```

If the Output is:

```
2 green

3 blue

4 yellow
```

How do i type '3' and the output is 'blue' or when i type '2' the output printed is 'green'?(For a number, the corresponding color should be printed after the random function is used)

Comment: Just shuffle `lst`…!? Then each element will have a random index (though zero based, not one based).

Answer (score 1):

Put the pairs in a dictionary:

```
pairs = {}
for a in range(1,4):
    l=random.choice(lst1)
    l1=random.choice(lst)
    pairs[l] = l1
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
if n in pairs:
    print(pairs[n])
else:
    print"Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Barmar's good answer, you can clean up the code a bit and also avoid getting the same number or color twice:

```
pairs = {l : l1 for l, l1 in zip(random.sample(lst1, 3), random.sample(lst, 3))}
```

`random.sample(lst1, 3)` will pick 3 *unique* elements of `lst1`, at random. Then we also pick 3 unique random elements from the other list. Then we zip those elements together into a list of pairs, and then we put them all into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) then [`list.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) in order to avoid duplicated keys and values, to have always three elements in dict(skipped user input, already shown in other answers):

```
import random

colors=['black','blue','green','red','yellow']
nums=[1,2,3,4,5]

res = {}
for _ in range(3):
    random.shuffle(colors)
    random.shuffle(nums)
    num, color = nums.pop(), colors.pop()
    res[num] = color

print(res)
#=> {4: 'green', 3: 'yellow', 1: 'black'}
print(res[1])
#=> black

print(colors, nums) # not used
#=> ['blue', 'red'] [2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for two lists - simply use  [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)
 over your `colors` and [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) them into a dict:

```
import random
colors=['black','blue','green','red','yellow']

# create the dict from a 3-parts sample, enumeration starting at 1
d = dict( enumerate(random.sample(colors,k=3), 1) )
```

**Test:**

```
for _ in range(5):
    d = dict( enumerate(random.sample(colors,k=3), 1) )
    print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: 'blue', 2: 'yellow', 3: 'black'}
{1: 'yellow', 2: 'green', 3: 'blue'}
{1: 'black', 2: 'green', 3: 'yellow'}
{1: 'black', 2: 'yellow', 3: 'red'}
{1: 'yellow', 2: 'green', 3: 'blue'}
```

You can access the color by `d[1]` through to `d[3]`.

Doku:

- [enumerate(iterable, startvalue)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)